# Asp.net Membership provider fails to connect to on premise SQL Server when deployed to Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to port one of my asp.net MVC (V 4.0/ .Net Framework 4.5) to Azure as app service.  My database is SQL Server and my application connects to it using [Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).  My application uses SQL Authentication to connect to database.  Everything works fine when deployed to IIS server on one of our locally hosted servers, but the authentication feature breaks when deployed to Azure as an app service.

My controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public virtual ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //var v = Membership.GetAllUsers();
                try
                {
                    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.ToString());
                }
                
            }
```

Error on Azure:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
> 'OSUser'. at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
> DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
> sqlAuthProviderManager) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
> System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context,
> Boolean revertImpersonate) at
> System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String
> connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) at
> System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String
> username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String&
> password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32&
> failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
> Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime&
> lastActivityDate) at
> System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String
> username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate,
> Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) at
> System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
> username, String password) at
> WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
> username, String password) at
> USC.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String
> returnUrl) in D:\a\1\s\USC\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 36
> ClientConnectionId:b1f6b763-80f6-47f0-9a50-c70ab30635bd Error
> Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

Any ideas???  Thanks!

Comment: Does the connection string use a FQDN for the server, or an IP address? Since hybrid connections can't use UDP you can't use instance names (which require access to the SQL Browser service on udp/1434), so do you specify a port number in your connection string?

Comment: Also... be aware that the tcp/3306 port used in the link you provided is for a MySQL database connection. The default port for Microsoft SQL Servers (the \MSSQLSERVER instance name) is 1433.

Comment: The connection string itself works fine for other access of the website. Only fails for membership provider

Answer (score 0):

The message "Login failed for User" is a generic error message that might have a variety of causes. The error message sent to the client does not include information about the reason for the login failure for security reasons.

You need to give this user logon permission to SQL Server and access to the database: [Create a Login - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

It may be that the database you're connecting to was generated using an older version of the.NET Framework's aspnet regsql.exe tool when you deployed your app. Try using the same version of aspnet regsql that you used locally to create and configure the membership database. Maybe you just utilised SQL Express and the /App Data folder locally.

In both databases, compare the table structure. Please compare the AspNet Membership table.

You could even refer to : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: [Login failed for user | The ASP.NET Forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/1151083.aspx?System%20Data%20SqlClient%20SqlException%20Login%20failed%20for%20user)

Troubleshooting: Login Failed for User 'x' | [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms366351(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)